# Closed points and discrete valuation rings, Exercise in Ravi Vakil's notes 12.7.B

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am working on the problem in Vakil's notes exercise 12.7.B which asks

> Suppose $X$ is an irreducible Noetherian separated curve. If $p\in X$
>   is a regular closed point, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is a discrete
>   valuation ring, so each regular point yields a discrete valuation on
>   $K(X)$. Use the previous exercise to show that the distinct points
>   yield distinct valuations.

I have no problems with the first part. It is the second which I am having problem...

Given two regular points $p$ and $q$ in $X$ that give the same valuations on $K(X)$, how do I show that they are equal? It says use the previous exercise, which is the easier part of the valuative criterion for separatedness, but I can't find a way to use this to prove that $p$ and $q$ are the same.

So first I start with suppose that the valuations are the same, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}=\mathcal{O}_{X,q}:=A$ giving the same function fields $K(A)$. How should I continue from here?

Comment: Have you done exercise 12.7A before?

Comment: Yep. I have done that. But I am not sure if that has anything to do with 12.7B.

Comment: Hint: it does. Read the valuative criterion for separatedness.

Comment: I have tried and I got more confused by the criterion. So my strategy was to prove that if $p$ and $q$ have the same valuation ring, then $p=q$. So we have two different morphisms say $f$ and $g$, with $f,\, g:\text{Spec}K(A)\rightarrow X$ sending the point $\{*\}$ to $p$ and $q$. I would be done if there exists exactly one $\text{Spec}A\rightarrow X$, which would mean $f=g$. But the nature of $\text{Spec}{A}\rightarrow X$ depends on $f$ and $g$ and not the other way round.... so I thought that the valuative criterion is not useful here. What else should I know?

Comment: The valuative criteria says that there exists at most one map $\mathrm{Spec} A\to X$, so if you have two, they must be the same. I posted an answer with full details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\mathcal{O}_{X,p}=\mathcal{O}_{X,q}$. Recall that $K(A)=K(X)$. Set up the usual commutative diagram (my apologies on the formatting- Tikz doesn't work here, and it's the only diagram markup I know) where the top row is 
$$\mathrm{Spec} K(A) \to X$$
and the bottom row is $$\mathrm{Spec} A \to \mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$$

with vertical morphisms as $\mathrm{Spec}(i)$ (where $i: A\to K(A)$ is the inclusion) and the unique map to $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$.

The morphism on the top row sends $\mathrm{Spec} K(A)$ to the generic point of $X$, and the morphism on the bottom row is the unique morphism to $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$. $X$ separated is by definition equivalent to the morphism $X\to \mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ being separated.

There are two candidates for maps from $\mathrm{Spec} A\to X$ making the diagram commute: viewing $A$ as $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$, we can send the closed point to $p$ and the open point to the generic point of $X$; viewing $A$ as $\mathcal{O}_{X,q}$ we can send the closed point to $q$ and the open point to the generic point of $X$. By 12.7A, apply the valuative criteria for separatedness. This says there is at most one map $\mathrm{Spec} A\to X$ making the diagram commute. So our two candidates must in fact be the same map, or $p=q$.

Comment: You can use AMScd. I think there's a meta post showing a basic example (which is really all you can do with AMScd anyway).

Comment: @Hoot: Thanks for the tip- I'll see if I can get that working.

Comment: @KReiser  Thanks! I didn't think of sending $\text{Spec}K(A)$ to the generic point of $X$. But one thing which I do not understand is this: why should $K(X)=K(A)$?. Because if I understand correctly, $K(X)$ is the function field at the generic point $\eta$ defined by $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}/\frak{m}_{\eta}$ where $\frak{m}_{\eta}$ is the maximal ideal, which need not necessarily be $K(A)$ (unless we assume $X$ is reduced (or suffices it to be regular because then its stalk is a regular local ring and hence $X$ is reduced...)

Comment: I doubt he wants to write $K(X)$ if $X$ isn't integral, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I would also assume Vakil means that $X$ is integral (and thus reduced).

Comment: For one time I thought the question was asking that two different regular points gives rise to two different discrete valuations on $K(A)$ rather than $K(X)$, but I ignored it because I thought it wasn't a serious problem... but it is a bit irritating to try to figure it out why $K(X)$ is used instead.

Comment: First, we should take $X$ integral so that we can reasonably talk about $K(X)$. Then, $K(A)$ and $K(X)$ coincide (since the local ring at the generic point is a localization of the local ring at any closed point $p$). Don't worry too much about this part of the problem- concentrate on the valuative criteria and the diagram.

Comment: Ok sure, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Having worked through a lot of this book: he's often sloppy about what "curve" means. It's best to add in enough hypotheses until the spirit of the exercise comes out. For the beginner this is hard, admittedly.